# How to decrease memory allocation when reading text files from NSBundle

Tags: ios, memory-management

I am using some very large text files (with .txt postfix). They are mostly over a hundred lines. I use this two lines of code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"biography" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *biointroString=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Everything works fine and the text are displayed (although with a slight delay). When i run the application with instruments i see my memory usage going above two and three hundred megabytes. This does not make sense to me since the text files are only a few kilobytes each. Does anyone know a better way to read text files without this much memory usage?

Comment: Use the Allocations and Leaks portions of Instruments and see where the memory usage is really coming from.

Comment: It is mostly coming from VM:UILabel(CALayer) , CTRun and VM:CoreAnimation. Sorry im not very familiar with instruments. And there is no leak by the way.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Rashid.

Comment: Thank you @Brian im glad to be here with such a cool crowd.

Comment: How many files are you reading in succession?

Comment: Check `@autoreleasepool`.

Comment: "I am using some very large text files (with .txt postfix). They are mostly over a hundred lines." You meant "mostly hundred of *thousands* lines"? If not, your problem is certainly elsewhere. ;)  (hint: Nekak Kinich)

Comment: @PeterCetinski one at a time. Im using this accordion style table that displays one file and dismisses it when i tap one other cells or close the current cell.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper well if you mean thousands of lines in iphone screen yeah you could say that! I was referring to the PC screen when i said hundreds of lines. Ok lets say there are way to many lines of text to be displayed. like 800 lines. is it just too much for iphone? (i know it defeats the whole purpose of writing small but handy apps on a mobile)

Comment: What I wanted to point out is, that 800 lines of text will not cause memory issues. You can safely handle and allocate text in the range of 1 MByte. If you have memory issues, use Instruments as suggested by rmaddy, in order to figure where that comes from. What you do with 800 lines of text on an iPhone screen, is a different question, though   ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Ok so the problem is coming from somewhere else. I ran instruments and its mostly coming from UILabel that is displaying the text. By the way i used a class that creates dynamic height labels. I just noticed that it uses a lot of label and text related methods. Is it possible that this is causing the problem?

Comment: From the distance, I cannot tell. You should use instruments to locate where the allocations take place. If you need help solving the issue, you should complement your post with your findings and provide more detailed information (e.g. locate your code which eventually leads to allocations, provide an image from Instruments, and any other details which may help)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Ok i will do that. Thanks. One more thing i did a little experiment. I created a new project. This time i used textView and read the same .txt files using NSbundle (the same code i wrote in my question). Ran instruments and still the same problem. Memory allocation goes over 200 and 300 MB!